# Webpack не помещает картинки при сборке в папку dist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, сборка

webpack.config.js:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: "css-loader"
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: 'assets/img/[name].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: "./src/index.html" }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
  ]
};
```

файл style.css:

```
.App {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.App::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;

  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

  background-image: url(/src/assets/img/regulations-download.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

структура проекта:

- dist
- src
- components

  - App

    - index.js
    - style.css
- index.html
- index.js
- webpack.config.js

Если указываю путь к картинке относительно рабочего каталога:

background-image: url(/src/assets/img/regulations-download.png)

то при сборке в папку dist не добавляется это изображение, работает только если указываю

background-image: url(../../assets/img/regulations-download.png)

Comment: Ну так емнип как раз относительные пути и надо указывать, а оно потом "компилирует" это всё как надо.

Comment: А нельзя как-то настроить это, чтобы можно было указывать 1 способом относительно рабочего каталога. Иногда слишком большая вложенность бывает и неудобно переходить наверх ../../..

Comment: webpack вообще игнорирует абсолютные пути

Answer (score 4):

Решил следующим образом, может кому-то пригодится. Добавил alias в webpac конфиг:

```
const path = require("path");

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      images: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/img/'),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: "css-loader"
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: 'assets/img/[name].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: "./src/index.html" }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
  ]
};
```

В css файле теперь вместо url(../../assets/img/regulations-download.png) можно использовать url(~images/regulations-download.png);

```
.App {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.App::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;

  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

  background-image: url(~images/regulations-download.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```